# How to concatenate conditions in fish

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, fish

I am trying to use a if block in fish using two conditions. The idea is simple:
I want to check if an image file is too wide, too tall, or both.
So I wrote the following script.

```
#!/bin/fish

set bla (identify $argv[1])
set blabla (string split ' ' $bla)
set siiz (string split x $blabla[3])

set xsiz $siiz[1]
set ysiz $siiz[2]


if test (test $xsiz -gt 1600) -a (test $ysiz -gt 900)
    echo "both $xsiz $ysiz"
else if test $ysiz -gt 900
    echo "tall"
else if test $xsiz -gt 1600
    echo "wide"
end
```

And I already performed check to see that the variables xsiz and ysiz have the right
values.
But no matter what I pass to the script, it always returns "both" (even using images of 20 by 20 pixels)´
If I try to pass the `test` command without the parenthesis or the inner `test` commands, fish will complain about not recognized commands.
The docs have none examples about a composed condition like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Note that [command substitution](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#expand-command-substitution) doesn't capture the exit status of the command except for the special case of the `set` command. Your version is equivalent to this:

```
if test (false) -a (true)
    echo yes
end
```

That always echoes "yes" (why the `false` doesn't cause the test to evaluate to false is a quirk of the language that should be fixed, IMHO).

Just do a single test:

```
if test $xsiz -gt 1600 -a $ysiz -gt 900
```